# Checkbox show img

Tags: javascript, html, image, checkbox

I'm trying to make it so, when you checked/uncheck a checkbox, the img appears/disappears. As of now, when I checked a box, all 4 of the images appear instead of just the one. Also I was wondering is it wrong to use document.ready multiple times? This is what I have:

```
  Js:
    $(document).ready
    (
    function() 
    {
        $("#pump").hide();
        $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
         this.checked?$("#pump").show():$("#pump").hide();
        });
    });

    $(document).ready
    (
    function() 
    {
        $("#ski").hide();
        $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
         this.checked?$("#ski").show():$("#ski").hide();
        });
    });

    $(document).ready
    (
    function() 
    {
        $("#ship").hide();
        $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
         this.checked?$("#ship").show():$("#ship").hide();
        });
    });

    $(document).ready
    (
    function() 
    {
        $("#sun").hide();
        $("input:checkbox").change(function(){
         this.checked?$("#sun").show():$("#sun").hide();
        });
    });

                                 Html:
                                <div>
                <input type="checkbox"></input>
                <label> Pumpkins </label>
                <img src="images/pumpkins.jpg" id="pump">

                <input type="checkbox"></input>
                <label> Ski Resort </label>
                <img src="images/ski resort.jpg" id="ski">

                <input type="checkbox"></input>
                <label> Bahamas </label>
                <img src="images/bahamas.jpg" id="sun">

                <input type="checkbox"></input>
                <label> Cruise </label>
                <img src="images/cruise.jpg" id="ship">

            </div>
```

Comment: You can just use css. and + operator

Comment: So - the code is doing exactly what you want.
You have added 4 functions that each add a listener to the change event. So - when a change event occurs, they all get triggered.

Comment: Also - when you have 4 functions with exactly the same code and different arguments - it usually means you're doing something wrong. You probably just need the one, and pass it the ID of the div as an argument...

Comment: Also should mention that the Selector $("input:checkbox") will always find the first occurrence. So likely they are all listening to the same checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
   $("#pump").hide();
    $("#ski").hide();
     $("#sun").hide();
      $("#ship").hide();
  
});

$("#id1").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
      $("#pump").show();  
    }
    else{
      $("#pump").hide();
    }
});
$("#id2").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
      $("#ski").show();  
    }
    else{
      $("#ski").hide();
    }
});  
$("#id3").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
       $("#sun").show();   
    }
    else{
      $("#sun").hide();
    }
});
$("#id4").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $("#ship").show(); 
    }
    else{
        $("#ship").hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id = "id1" type="checkbox"></input>
                <label> Pumpkins </label>
                <img src="images/pumpkins.jpg" id="pump">

                <input id = "id2" type="checkbox"></input>
                <label> Ski Resort </label>
                <img src="images/ski resort.jpg" id="ski">

                <input id = "id3" type="checkbox"></input>
                <label> Bahamas </label>
                <img src="images/bahamas.jpg" id="sun">

                <input id = "id4" type="checkbox"></input>
                <label> Cruise </label>
                <img src="images/cruise.jpg" id="ship">
```

You need to create ids for your checkboxes.

And within your event listener for the checkbox, you have to check whether the box has been selected or not. I like tu use IF ELSE.

Comment: Thanks! That really helped!

Comment: If my answer answered, click accept answer, so that others, with the same doubt that you had, know there is a correct answer to solve their problems.